# Magento 2: How can I hide the customer custom attribute from backend customer create and edit from if the value is null?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

How can I hide the customer custom attribute if the value is null?

Ultimately I want to show this field on edit if it is not null and I don't want to show this field when we create a new customer

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Plugin for Customer Form Block:**

Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Form

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Form">
        <plugin name="hide_custom_attribute" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Adminhtml\Customer\Form" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
```

**Create the Plugin Class**

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Adminhtml\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Form as CustomerEditForm;

class Form
{
    public function afterGetFormHtml(CustomerEditForm $subject, $result)
    {
        // Replace 'custom_attribute_code' with your custom attribute's code
        if ($subject->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute_code')->getValue() === null) {
            $result = str_replace('<div class="admin__field', '<div style="display:none" class="admin__field', $result);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

After that clear cache.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```